# Going out of fullscreen in Minecraft crashes me, and mobs sometimes don't die and instead just the model of the mob remains in it's place

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I went to play on the new snapshot for the Caves and Cliffs update.I turned on fullscreen and set the controls and all that, made a new world, it turned night time, waited a bit in a hole, went outside, a bunch of mobs (including mobs that burn in sunlight) in the sunlight were no burning *or* responding to me. They just sat there and I couldn't hit them, then I went out of fullscreen to search up what was happening and my game crashed, Exit Code: 0. How do I fix these two problems and if I can't fix them is there any workarounds, because if I can't work around the problem or fix it I'll just have to deal with it which is kind of annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Snapshot

You are in a snapshot. Snapshots are like betas. They are sometimes slightly buggy, and sometimes **extremely buggy**. Snapshots always have bugs so there may not be a way to get around this.

Answer (score -1):

if you are using the minecraft default launcher, try the **multimc**, I can be some kind of error in the launcher in processing the game.

apparently if you change the java version to 11 lts, it increases perfomace, so it's a good tip, if it with a lot of lag;

obs: if you are in **windows**, the multimc lib is used in the twich, so if you install the twich and configure to play mineacraft, it should work
Good Luck;

Comment: Minecraft by default uses Java 8, why would you change it? I'm not saying this answer is wrong more just curious?

Comment: sorry, I thought that it could be a error with the version, I will edit it right now to make it right

Comment: no I’m not saying you can’t I was just curious. I looked it up and it looks like that will increase performance, so you should rollback